# Makefile inference rules ".c.o"

Tags: c, makefile

I was trying to learn makefiles, and I am unable to get inference rules to work.

As per my knowledge , the inference rule below would make a *.o file from *.c file.

```
.c.o :
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) –c $@
```

Whenever I tried typing in "make temp.c" , it says no targets found AND when I tried to do "make temp" , it uses the default make command which is built inside make. How can I force makefiles to use my inference rules?

Comment: `make temp.c` means "try to make `temp.c`", but `temp.c` already exists.  Try `make temp.o`.

Comment: If you want `make temp` to use your rule, your need to get rid of the default `.c:` rule (GNU syntax: `%: %.c`) that takes priority -- just add that as a line with no actions to do that.

Comment: Thanks Oliver and Chris that worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be able make `temp.o` given `temp.c`, the rule needs to be:

```
.c.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<
```

or, if you use GNU Make,

```
%.o: %.c:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<
```

Answer (score 1):

make should have used your make file.

What is the file name of your make file?

make will only, automatically, find 'makefile' and 'Makefile'

Then you can write the command line as:

```
make myTarget
```

If you have used any other name, then you need to write that command line as:

```
 make -f myMakefile  myTarget
```